# Airflow catchup weekdays only

Tags: cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Running a historical import each day in december 2018 requires a Dag that catches up with a chron expression '0 0 12 * * MON-FRI'.
Why does the scheduler run weekends when the dag starts up and catchup=True? 
Does the catchup parameter respect the schedule interval?

Comment: Shouldn't your cron be 0 0 12 * MON-FRI (5 digits) ? Because this is non-standard cron, it may or may not work on airflow scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression [doesn't work](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_12_*_*_MON-FRI). But [0 0 * 12 MON-FRI](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_12_MON-FRI) or [0 0 * 12 1-5](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_12_1-5) would.

Airflow uses `croniter` and you can play from home with:

```
$ cal 12 2018
   December 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31

$ python -c '
from croniter import croniter as cr
from datetime import datetime as dt
c=cr("0 0 * 12 MON-FRI", dt(2018,12,1))
for i in range(1,31):
  print(f"{i:>2}: ", c.get_next(dt))'
 1:  2018-12-03 00:00:00
 2:  2018-12-04 00:00:00
 3:  2018-12-05 00:00:00
 4:  2018-12-06 00:00:00
 5:  2018-12-07 00:00:00
 6:  2018-12-10 00:00:00
 7:  2018-12-11 00:00:00
 8:  2018-12-12 00:00:00
 9:  2018-12-13 00:00:00
...
21:  2018-12-31 00:00:00
22:  2019-12-02 00:00:00
23:  2019-12-03 00:00:00
24:  2019-12-04 00:00:00
25:  2019-12-05 00:00:00
26:  2019-12-06 00:00:00
27:  2019-12-09 00:00:00
28:  2019-12-10 00:00:00
29:  2019-12-11 00:00:00
30:  2019-12-12 00:00:00
```

It should not "run weekends" but you may find it confusing that the `execution_date` (determined by the `start_date` and `schedule_interval`) is not the date when the the DAG is *run*. E.G. The `dag_run` scheduled for #1 above is going to start running when #2 is past, etc. Also, by default these would be UTC, so run #5 there would start at #6 UTC, which in NYC would be: `2018-12-09 19:00:00-05:00`

See:

```
python -c '
from croniter import croniter as cr; from datetime import datetime as dt
from pendulum import datetime as pdt, timezone as ptz
c=cr("0 0 * 12 MON-FRI", pdt(2018,12,1))
for i in range(1,31):
 print(f"{i:>2}: ", ptz("America/New_York").convert(c.get_next(dt)))'
 1:  2018-12-02 19:00:00-05:00
 2:  2018-12-03 19:00:00-05:00
 3:  2018-12-04 19:00:00-05:00
 4:  2018-12-05 19:00:00-05:00
 5:  2018-12-06 19:00:00-05:00
 6:  2018-12-09 19:00:00-05:00
 7:  2018-12-10 19:00:00-05:00
 8:  2018-12-11 19:00:00-05:00
 9:  2018-12-12 19:00:00-05:00
10:  2018-12-13 19:00:00-05:00
11:  2018-12-16 19:00:00-05:00
12:  2018-12-17 19:00:00-05:00
13:  2018-12-18 19:00:00-05:00
14:  2018-12-19 19:00:00-05:00
15:  2018-12-20 19:00:00-05:00
16:  2018-12-23 19:00:00-05:00
17:  2018-12-24 19:00:00-05:00
18:  2018-12-25 19:00:00-05:00
19:  2018-12-26 19:00:00-05:00
20:  2018-12-27 19:00:00-05:00
21:  2018-12-30 19:00:00-05:00
22:  2019-12-01 19:00:00-05:00
23:  2019-12-02 19:00:00-05:00
24:  2019-12-03 19:00:00-05:00
25:  2019-12-04 19:00:00-05:00
26:  2019-12-05 19:00:00-05:00
27:  2019-12-08 19:00:00-05:00
28:  2019-12-09 19:00:00-05:00
29:  2019-12-10 19:00:00-05:00
30:  2019-12-11 19:00:00-05:00
```